# How to persist before application crash in android?

Tags: android

I have a form and and a camera button in an application. First, one fills the form then launches camera. In case, camera crashes then the details entered in form is gone. Any way to store and restore the details before and after crash ? Storing and restoring using XML or SQL DB is very heavy.  Since there are many places it is used.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using [preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)? That might fit your needs